# Как редактировать уже размещенный сайт на хостинге?

Tags: wordpress, seo

Здраствуйте, у меня есть простой Landing на Wordpress. Он уже размещен и работает.

Возникла потребность изменить часть кода в теме, как сделать это правильно так, чтобы сайт не потерял позиции в топе?

Comment: Как минимум не удалять теги семантического значения.

Comment: Я так понимаю печь идёт о сео оптимизации сайта. Главное не удалять теги, либо если нужно их удалить - то просто заменять другими тегами. Делать все просто по аналогии.

Answer (score 1):

Обновление информации раз в полгода повышает позиции страницы, проверенно. Не меняйте Title и discription а также заголовки H1. Остальное можно править спокойно, главное не наделать ошибок в коде.

Answer (score 1):

У вас должны быть доступы по ftp и в панель управления хостингом. Если нету, то обратитесь к своему программисту, либо пишите в тех.поддержку хостера. Они обязаны вам их предоставить. 
После чего заходите и редактируете нужные вам файлы. Главное, не редактируйте в них те места, на которые обращают поисковые системы, например, title, метатеги, заголовки и т.д.